# Rails5: How can I use the ActiveRecord "OR" query with "includes"?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children

  enum status: {
     status1: 0,
     status2: 1     
  }
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end

# error
# "Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:references]"
combination = Parent.status1.or(Parent.status2.includes(:children).where(children: {name: 'ABC'}))
```

I want to get the data "status1" or "status2 has children named 'ABC'", but error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The [`or` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) takes another relation that has a similar filter pattern, and combines it with the already-existing filters on the object being called.

For example, `Parent.status1.or(Parent.status2)` would give you a set of records that have either `status: 1` or `status: 2`.

*(In case someone is not familiar with it, the example in the question also uses [`enum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), which allows filtering the enum's attribute value using the name of the value. `#status1` and `#status2` in this case correspond to `{ status: 0 }` and `{status: 1}` respectively.)*

In order to call more relation methods to modify the final result, you must call them **on the result** of calling `#or`, like this:

```
Parent.status1.or(Parent.status2).includes(:children).where(children: {name: 'ABC'})
```

---

Based on your comment I see now that you want records that either (have `status1`) or (have `status2` *and have a matching `children` record*).

Note that in order to use a relation in a `where` (like `where(children: { name: value })` you must *join* with the related table (`joins(:children).where(children: { name: value })`. It seems that ActiveRecord will infer the join if you use only `includes`, but that's not documented as far as I can tell. This is why `or` sees the two relations as incompatible: one has `children` in the references list, while the other does not.

If you write the `where` clause by hand as a string, it does not change the references list, so `or` does not see the relation as incompatible. When you write a `where` clause by hand, you must *explicitly* use `joins`:

```
Parent.status1.joins(:children).or(Parent.status2.joins(:children).where("children.name = 'ABC'"))
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: What I want to do is that to get data "status1 OR (status2 AND children.name = ABC)".

So finally, I tried it by following code.
                                                                                                                
`st1_ids = Parent.status1.pluck(:id)`
`st2_and_name_is_abc_ids = Parent.status2.pluck(:id)`
`conbination = Parent.where(id: st1_ids + st2_and_name_is_abc_ids)`

Comment: I did misunderstand your question. I've updated my answer. Can I suggest [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write more effective questions? If you had included a more detailed list of what you expected, you might have gotten a better answer more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling "includes" on the final or result.

```
parent = Parent.status1.or(Parent.status2)
parent.includes(:chilren).where(children: {name: "ABC"})
```